# angular ngbootstrap radio button color is not changing dynamically

Tags: css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to change color of button on button pressed or click event. Even border-color background color will also do. But this code snippet is not applying required colors. It seems method is getting called but colors are not applying.

> buttons-radioreactive.html

```
<form [formGroup]="radioGroupForm">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic" formControlName="model">
        <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
          <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="1" > Left (pre-checked)
        </label>
        <label #value1 ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary" (click)="call()">
          <input ngbButton type="radio" value="middle"> Middle
        </label>
        <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
          <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="false"> Right
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <pre>{{radioGroupForm.value['model']}}</pre>
```

> buttons-radioreactive.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
    import {ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
    import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core/';


    @Component({
      selector: 'ngbd-buttons-radioreactive',
      templateUrl: './buttons-radioreactive.html',
      styleUrls: ['./buttons-radioreactive.css']
    })
    export class NgbdButtonsRadioreactive implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('value1')el:ElementRef;

      public radioGroupForm: FormGroup;

      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.radioGroupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          'model': 1
        });
      }

      call(){
        console.log("Called before")
        this.el.nativeElement.color="orange";
        console.log("Called after")
      }
    }
```

> buttons-radioreactive.css

```
    .pressed {
  border-color: #ff9800;
  color: orange;
}

.un-pressed {
  border-color: #ffffff;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use ngClass :

in component:

```
toggle : boolean = true;
call(){
  this.toggle = !this.toggle;
}
```

in html:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic" [(ngModel)]="model">
    <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
          <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="1" > Left (pre-checked)
        </label>
        <label #value1 ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary"
        [ngClass]="{'pressed': toggle , 'un-pressed': !toggle}">
          <input ngbButton type="radio" value="middle"  (click)="call()"> Middle // consider to add click to input
        </label>
        <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
          <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="false"> Right
        </label>
      </div>
    <hr>
<pre>{{test}}</pre>
```

css:

```
.pressed {
  border-color: #ff9800 !important; // important
  color: orange !important;
}

.un-pressed {
  border-color: #ffffff !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9qysdr)

Comment: Sorry for late reply.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgb1rl)

In your HTML, you're calling the call() method from the 'middle' radio button only... hence the effect you wanted is applying to it only.

```js
import {  Component,  OnInit,  Renderer2 ,ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {  FormBuilder,  FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {  ViewChild} from '@angular/core/';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-buttons-radioreactive',
  templateUrl: './buttons-radioreactive.html',
  styles: [`
          .pressed {
  border-color: #ff9800;
  color: orange;
}

.un-pressed {
  border-color: #ffffff;
  color: white;
}
`]
})
export class NgbdButtonsRadioreactive implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('value1') el: ElementRef;

  public radioGroupForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.radioGroupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'model': 1
    });
  }

  call() {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'pressed');
  }
}
```

Comment: I clicked on middle button only. Its not applying there

Comment: @Aniket: what happens when you click on the middle radio button in the link i pasted above... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgb1rl ??

Comment: @AkberIqbal, I think he want to make a custom class to buttons

Comment: Thank you but the problem was actually realted to ng-botstrap. Again thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you can assign a custom class to your buttons, see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmzfs7?file=app/buttons-radio.ts)

```
styles:[`
    .btn-custom.focus
    {
      outline:none!important;
      box-shadow:0 0 0 0
    }
    .btn-custom{
      background-color:orange;
      color:white;

    }
    .btn-custom.active{
      background-color:red;
      color:white;
      border-color:firebrick;
    }
  `
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic" [(ngModel)]="model">
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-custom">
    <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="1"> Left (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-custom">
    <input ngbButton type="radio" value="middle"> Middle
  </label>
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-custom">
    <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="false"> Right
  </label>
</div>
<hr>
<pre>{{model}}</pre>
```